# Eclipse egit documentation

Tags: java, eclipse

i'm working a on a api yo use as proxy for github using java spring and maven and a stumbled upon the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.mylyn.github</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.egit.github.core</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.5</version>
</dependency>
```

I found it interesting since it saves me a lot of configuration and doing manually the api calls. But i'm having trouble finding any documentation. For instance getting the file from a specific pr.

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be a bridge between Mylyn and Github tasks, handling files looks out of its scope. However, you can [inspect the source code](https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github/blob/master/org.eclipse.mylyn.github.core/src/org/eclipse/mylyn/internal/github/core/pr/PullRequestConnector.java) or better than that, use [github API](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#list-pull-requests-files) to get what you want.